# Gcloud deploy specific files

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, app.yaml, gcloud

I am serving some static js files with app engine. I am deploying code via with 
 `gcloud preview app deploy .` This currently deploys all of my static files, is there a method to upload just a single js file in my static directory to app engine? Maybe a app.yaml config? I basically just need to scp file.js -> gcloud instance but would like to use gcloud tool if possible.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
default_expiration: "30d"
- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to upload a single random file to GAE, but take a look carefully at the logs when the app is being deployed: only the files that were changed since last deployment are being uploaded, so unless all your static files were edited - they are not going to be re-deployed every single time.

Comment: Sweet. I will take a closer look... Also looks like if I change my app.yaml to only include file.js it will only include file.js and remove all the other files previously deployed...

Comment: Right, deploying syncs your local files with the remote ones. It won't upload files that are already there and the same as the local ones, but it will remove them if you delist them.